# How can I install/use Visual Studio 2013 without virtualization/Hyper-V?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, virtualization

I recently enabled intel virtualization in my BIOS and installed HAXM in order to run virtual android devices. I also needed to enable this feature to run some 64 bit OS's on VMWare Workstation. After this, I installed Visual Studio 2013. After restarting my computer, the virtualization was not accessible by HAXM or VMWare workstation. In the CPU info program Speccy before installing Visual Studio it said "virtualization: supported, enabled" but after installation it said "virtualization: not supported"

Reverting to a Windows restore point before installation fixed the problem. I really dont need any virtualization for Visual Studio, but I'd like to have VS 2013. I could look into disabling the feature in VS after installation, but I'm not even sure that would work. Is there a way I can install VS 2013 without that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Also, I found the solution here that goes into a little more detail if anyone has this problem: http://www.windows8central.com/index.php/en/virtualization/item/3580-visual-studio-2013-breaks-virtualbox-and-vmware-due-to-hyper-v-conflict